# $scope not being injected/inherited from controller to directive with dot notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I'm having an issue with injecting/inheriting a scope from a controller to a directive. Importantly, the module is not separated into its own var.

```
angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['$scope, ...

]).directive('comments', ['$scope' ... //does not work!
```

Comment: `$scope` is **not a singleton**. It is injected as a local by `$compile` into controllers and also made available as the first argument of a directive's linking functions. It is not  available for injection in the directive construction function. However you can inject the **singletons providers**: `$rootScope`, `$http`, `$timeout`, `$q`, `$document`,  etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Why would they allow `$rootScope` (potentally rife with misuse) and not `$scope`?

Comment: `$rootScope` can be used for registering listeners with `$on` and emitting events with `$broadcast` and `$emit`. For more info see the [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Comment: `$scope` is a **local** injected by `$compile`. For more information on **controller locals** see the [AngularJS $compile API Reference -- controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bypassed `$scope` entirely with a couple of other scopes:

```
    .directive('comments', ['$stateParams', '$location', 'Articles',
  function ( $stateParams, $location, Articles) {

   if ($stateParams.articleId != null){

   var article = Articles.get({
        articleId: $stateParams.articleId
      });

   var comments = {articleId: article.articleId, created: Date.now, comment:"Hello, World!", user: "admin" };

       return{
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        template: "<div></div>"
       };
      }
     }
    ]);
```

Comment: Yes, you can inject almost anything **except `$scope`** in the directive constructor function. WIth `scope: true` the directives gets a new scope that inherits from its parent scope.

Comment: Well, in my case anyway, `$scope` not was inherited. same with false (supposed be a ref to the OG `$scope`)

Comment: If a directive has no parent scope, it inherits from `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't inject the scope into a directive as a dependency. Should be like this:

```
.directive([function() {
    return {
        "link": function($scope, $element, $attrs) { 
             //code here
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Is this similar to $complie and include? I tried that as well. Let me try this though. EDIT: got Argument 'ArticlesController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Where are you getting that error? What does your code look like now?

Comment: I got that error when I tried to inject `$scope` into a directive. My code now looks like my answer on this question.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to think about directives as black boxes. You provide it with some data and it updates/displays it. You can read all required info about directives [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and declare directive's inputs and outputs like this:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myParameter: '=' //this declares directive's interface (2 way binded)
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      console.log(scope.myParameter);
    }
  };
});
```

and then you can use this directive as:

```
<my-directive my-parameter='variable_declared_in_controller'></my-directive>
```

Comment: Yeah I might need to add another controller then, since I need to fetch more data (article comments) that I just have as static JSON for now.